# I want to make an icon, text in the different row by bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I want to make an icon, text in the different row by bootstrap4.

Guys, I am practising by bootstrap4 for beginner level; I am struggling; I could not make the icon in the centre in the first row and the subtitle by h3 in the second row.

I put text with h3 then add an icon by class, which affected the icon with the text in the same row.  However, this is not what I want.

Again, I changed the other way round, so I created three columns by the grid, and I put the icon into the div together, but the effect is even worse.....the style by h3 and the button text in the 3rd row has lost the text style.

Please advise the solution so that I could clear the challenge.

Thanks and highly appreciated!

[image: this is where I want to edit and fix]

[image: I want the effect like below]

```html
  <html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>
  <!-- Google Font -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;400;700&family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">

  <!-- css stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <!-- fontawesome -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e2fafd992e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap Script -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>

  
  <section id="features">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col fas fa-check-circle">
          <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
          <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col fas fa-bullseye">
          <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
          <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="fas fa-heart">
        <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
          <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I made it finally and I believe I solve this problem.
Thanks all

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="features-box col-lg-4 col-md-3">
    <i class="icon fas fa-check-circle fa-4x"></i>
    <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
    <p class="sub-title">So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="features-box col-lg-4 col-md-3">
    <i class="icon fas fa-bullseye fa-4x"></i>
    <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
    <p class="sub-title">We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="features-box col-lg-4 col-md-3">
    <i class="icon fas fa-heart fa-4x"></i>
    <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
    <p class="sub-title">Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```css
#title{background-color: #ff4c68;
color: #fff;
}

body {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}

.container-fluid{
  padding: 3% 15%
}

h1{
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 3.5rem;
line-height: 1.5;
}

h2{
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h3{
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}

p{
  color: #8f8f8f;
}

/* navigation bar */

.navbar{
  padding: 0 0 4.5rem;
}

.nav-item{
  padding: 0 18px 0 18px;
}

.nav-link{
font-size: 1.2rem;
font-family: "Montserrat";
font-weight: 400;
}


.navbar-brand{
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* download buttons */

.download-buttons{
  position: relative;
  margin: 5% 3% 5% 0;
   right: 40px;
}

/* title-image */
.title-image{
  width:60%;
  -ms-transform: rotate(25deg); /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform:rotate(25deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate (25deg);
  transform: rotate(25deg);
}

/* features-section */
#features{
  padding: 7% 15%;
}

.sub-title{
  font-size: 15px;
}

.features-box{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5%;
}

.icon{
  color: #ef8172;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.icon:hover{
color: #ff4c68;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>
  <!-- Google Font -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;400;700&family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">

  <!-- css stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <!-- fontawesome -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e2fafd992e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap Script -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>

<!-- Features -->

  <section id="features">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="features-box col-lg-4 col-md-3">
        <i class="icon fas fa-check-circle fa-4x"></i>
        <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
        <p class="sub-title">So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="features-box col-lg-4 col-md-3">
        <i class="icon fas fa-bullseye fa-4x"></i>
        <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
        <p class="sub-title">We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="features-box col-lg-4 col-md-3">
        <i class="icon fas fa-heart fa-4x"></i>
        <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
        <p class="sub-title">Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>


  </section>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `text-center` class to your `row` to center the icons:

```
<div class="row text-center">
    ...
</div>
```

To fix the subtitles in the columns, you need to move the icon classes out of the columns' styles. Right now you have something like this:

```
<div class="col fas fa-icon">
    <h3>Subtitle</h3>
</div>

...rest of the columns
```

The `h3` subtitle's styles (the whole column's styles, actually) are overwritten by the `fas fa-icon` icon class. Place the icon *within* the column instead, like so, to solve that problem:

```
<div class="col">
    <i class="fas fa-icon"></i>
    <h3>Subtitle</h3>
</div>

...rest of the columns
```

[image: demo]

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TinDog</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;400;700&family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e2fafd992e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <section id="features">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                    <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
                    <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col"><i class="fas fa-bullseye"></i>
                    <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
                    <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
                    <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
                    <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @anpanman -  Let me know if there's anything unclear in my answer or if you have any other questions on it, so I can clarify.

Comment: Thanks and I want to know, how could I enlarge the image bigger?

Comment: I was trying to add css for .i class {width:100%;} but no effect.

Comment: and i also tried to add the padding-top: 30px; in the css but it could not work.  what i added in CSS was .icon{  width:100%;   padding-top: 30px;} and HTML is   <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col icon"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
          <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
          <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
        </div>

Comment: @anpanman The FontAwesome Icons have documentation you should probably read if you want to know how to use them correctly. Simply goto their website and read the docs! Here is the doc article about how to size the icons larger [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/sizing-icons)

Comment: @anpanman - Okay, try adding `style="margin: 30px"` to the `row` div instead of the columns to add a margin to the whole row. Also you can add the class `fa-2x` to double the size of the icons which looks like what you're looking for. If you want to set a custom icon size, set the `font-size` of the icon to whatever you want.